# PDF to Image converter code error in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

Unable to run the code in VS code with python version 3.8.1:-
Coming with below error in terminal

pdftojpg.py

```
import os
import tempfile
#import cv2
from pdf2image import convert_from_path

filename = 'E:/djcodes/pyproject/ID.pdf'

with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as path:
     images_from_path = convert_from_path(filename, output_folder=path, last_page=1, first_page =0)

base_filename  =  os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(filename))[0] + '.jpg'     

save_dir = 'E:/djcodes/pyproject/image'

for page in images_from_path:
    page.save(os.path.join(save_dir, base_filename), 'JPEG')

#img = cv2.imread(save_dir+os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(filename))[0]+'jpeg')
```

Terminal error:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\asus\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.2.64397\pythonFiles\ptvsd_launcher.py", line 48, in <module>
    main(ptvsdArgs)
  File "c:\Users\asus\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.2.64397\pythonFiles\lib\python\old_ptvsd\ptvsd\__main__.py", line 432, in main
    run()
  File "c:\Users\asus\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.2.64397\pythonFiles\lib\python\old_ptvsd\ptvsd\__main__.py", line 300, in run_file
    setup_connection()
  File "c:\Users\asus\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.2.64397\pythonFiles\lib\python\old_ptvsd\ptvsd\__main__.py", line 288, in setup_connection
    if not daemon.wait_for_launch(addr):
  File "c:\Users\asus\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.2.64397\pythonFiles\lib\python\old_ptvsd\ptvsd\runner.py", line 61, in wait_for_launch
    _, start_session = self.start_client(addr)
  File "c:\Users\asus\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.2.64397\pythonFiles\lib\python\old_ptvsd\ptvsd\daemon.py", line 217, in start_client
    connect(client, addr)
  File "c:\Users\asus\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.2.64397\pythonFiles\lib\python\old_ptvsd\ptvsd\socket.py", line 197, in connect
    sock.connect(addr)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

Please help to resolve the issue

Comment: The error seems to have nothing to do with your code, but is related to python visual studio runner. Can a simple program like print("hello world") run ? Blind usual ideas of windows solutions : restart visual studio, restart windows, check firewall :)

Comment: Notice the error readout, one of your vscode extensions is trying to establish a socket connection, and the target machine is refusing it. This is not an error from your program

Comment: But normal printing is working fine. As I'm getting the output also in VS code.

Comment: H All,  please help on the below issue.